# WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations - DownloadStringAsync - Scraping

Tags: c#, webclient, blockingcollection

First of all I have read the similar questions and they don't give me a coherent explanation. I use `BlockingCollection<WebClient> ClientQueue` to provide Webclients. I give them a handling function and start the async scraping :

```
// Create queue of WebClient instances
BlockingCollection<WebClient> ClientQueue = new BlockingCollection<WebClient>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   ClientQueue.Add(new WebClient());
}

//Triggering Async Calls
foreach (var item in source)
{
   var worker = ClientQueue.Take();
   worker.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) => HandleJson(sender, e, ClientQueue, item);
   worker.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
}

public static void HandleJson(object sender, EventArgs e, BlockingCollection<WebClient> ClientQueue, string item)
{
   var res = (DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs) e;
   var jsonData = res.Result;
   var worker = (WebClient) sender;
   var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonData);
   // Record the data
   while (worker.IsBusy) Thread.Sleep(5); // wait for the webClient to be free
   ClientQueue.Add(worker);
 }
```

I get this error message:

> WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations.

Other threads:

- Here answer suggest the the issue is to wait until `WebClient.IsBusy = false` but I am doing this before puting back the webclient in the queue. I don't understand why the client cannot perform a new request after making itself `IsBusy=false`
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9765812/7111121
- Here it suggests to use recycle webclients to optimize the process
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7474959/2132352
- Here it suggests to instanciate a new WebClient (easy solution of course but I don't want something hiding the way the objects used works). It also suggest to cancel the operation but this has not helped.

Comment: Show us how you're filling the queue

Comment: ok I have edited the question to show more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that each time particular WebClient is taken from queue, you register new event handler for `worker.DownloadStringCompleted` event without deregistering previous event handler - so event handlers accrues. As a consequence, `HandleJson` is called multiple times after async download completes and thus `ClientQueue.Add(worker)` returns the same client to the queue multiple times too. It is then just a matter of time before two concurrent downloads are issued on the same WebClient.

This can be easily fixed by registering event handler just once during WebClient creation, and removing `item` parameter from `HandleJson` method.

```
BlockingCollection<WebClient> ClientQueue = new BlockingCollection<WebClient>();
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    var worker = new WebClient();
    worker.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) => HandleJson(sender, e, ClientQueue);
    ClientQueue.Add(worker);
}
```

If parameter `item` is required, pass it as a parameter to `DownloadStringAsync(uri, item)` and read it from `res.UserState`:

```
foreach (var item in source)
{
   var worker = ClientQueue.Take();
   worker.DownloadStringAsync(uri, item);
}

public static void HandleJson(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e, BlockingCollection<WebClient> ClientQueue)
{
    string item = (string)res.UserState;
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you. Perfect answer. Seems more than obvious now. Do you have a suggestion for something more elegant than while (worker.IsBusy) Thread.Sleep(5); ?

Comment: I believe that checking `IsBusy` is completely useless in your case, because it will always be `false` before `DownloadStringCompleted` event handler is called - at least in `WebClient`'s [reference implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/4fe4349175f4c5091d972a7e56ea12012f1e7170/System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs#L1763)